# Problems with making a lamp database in ubuntu

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, lamp, database

I'm trying to create a lamp-server database. When I go to **localhost** in my browser the default apache "It's working" page is displayed. But when I'm trying to see my database with **localhost/posts** I get the error message 404. Posts is a table in a database called cake.

I've tried multiple times trying to remove everything and start again from scratch. This is the tutorial I'm following: [Swift: Using External Databases and API's Part 1: Setting Up The Server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYElY4ewq_o)

These are my config files.
Apache2.conf

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

Timeout 300

KeepAlive On

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 5

User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel warn

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

Include ports.conf

var/www.

<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""     combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
```

And the cake.conf:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/skip/cake/
    <Directory /home/skip/cake/>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/cake-access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/cake-error.log

    LogLevel debug

    <FilesMatch \"\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$\">

    </FilesMatch>

    BrowserMatch \"MSIE [2-6]\" \
            nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    BrowserMatch \"MSIE [17-9]\" ssl-unclean-shutdown

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the folder permission. Check the folder and file permissions of the application folder.As well as verify the path too.